# Evil characters and magic in Pathfinder Society organized play

Tags: alignment, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

If a Pathfinder Society player brings a 'typically evil' character to a Pathfinder Society game, what should the GM and other players do? This also can extend to characters casting magic with the evil category, such as 'Create Undead'. I'm assuming that the character performs evil actions, but doesn't have an evil alignment (yet).

Create Undead (Uncommon, Evil, Necromancy):
https://2e.aonprd.com/Rituals.aspx?ID=10

Section 10 of the PFS2 guide forbids evil alignments for characters:
http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pfs2edplayer-basics/

Infamy and Alignment Infractions
http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pathfinder-2-0-gm-basics/

Answer (score 3):

This is covered more in the [GM section](http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pathfinder-2-0-gm-basics/) of the Organized Play guide. Players are expected to contribute to a positive playing experience at the table, including avoiding evil acts. The PFS guide articulates this in a beautiful and direct way:

> Players are responsible for their characters’ actions. A player’s perception of what their character would do in a particular situation is never more important than the experience of other players at the table.

### Infamy and Alignment

The in-game solution is [Infamy](http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pathfinder-2-0-gm-basics/#infamy-and-alignment-infractions). When characters perform evil acts, or other inappropriate things (such as inappropriately deviant or criminal acts) the GM can award them Infamy points. A character with 3 Infamy points becomes evil, and thus inadmissible for Society play.

Lower levels of infamy have more moderate consequences, such as limiting the level of equipment they can use.

### GM-Alterations to Game

In some circumstances, evil activity is relatively small and driven by the story. In Society play the GM is encouraged to make story-related changes to encourage a welcoming environment for all players.

Although this didn't match your description very well, it's worth noting that the GM does have this kind of discretion in their toolkit for managing evil activity.You can read more in the [Table Variation](http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pathfinder-2-0-gm-basics/#table-variation) section.

### Removing Disruptive Players

A more extreme situation occurs when the *player* is the problem, rather that the character. If the evil activity is disrupting the game or making other players uncomfortable, the event organizer can eject the player from the game. There is a reporting chain, and it may involve review by venture officers. See [Community Standards](http://www.organizedplayfoundation.org/encyclopedia/pathfinder-2-0-organized-play-basics/community-standards) for more info.

Comment: Would creating undead minions be considered an evil action in PFS, and therefore earn Infamy? I'm not keen on GMing for a necromancer or anti-paladin type character, but also don't want to deny a player's choices outright. It seems like a necromancer (sans undead minions) is distinctly different than someone with an undead horde. This line of questioning extends to fiendish summoning, etc.

Comment: @WilliamM-B That may be better as a distinct question. Also not to leave you hanging - but I'm not sure. So I need a moment to dig in to it :)

Comment: @WilliamM-B Actually, there is an answer for that. Would you care to post it as a new question and I'll answer it?

Comment: @indigochild You could also ask and answer your own questions (there's an option when making the question to simultaneously post your own answer). Regerdless, [OP has made the question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163452/would-creating-undead-minions-be-considered-an-evil-action-in-pfs-and-therefore); at least this way they get the Rep for bringing it up (=

Comment: @Ifusaso Exactly! If I posted it, the OP wouldn't get rep for upvotes on their good question.