# Would creating undead minions be considered an evil action in PFS, and therefore earn Infamy?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

Would creating undead minions be considered an evil action in PFS, and therefore earn Infamy? I'm not keen on GMing for a necromancer or anti-paladin type character, but also don't want to deny a player's choices outright. It seems like a necromancer (sans undead minions) is distinctly different than someone with an undead horde. This line of questioning extends to fiendish summoning, etc.

Comment: Create undead is a ritual in 2e, and thus carries the Uncommon trait. How did the character gain access to the ritual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although a ruling hasn't been presented for the 2E Pathfinder Society, the [1E FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1hh#v5748eaic9vho) explicitly addressed this:

> **Does casting evil spells cause an alignment infraction?**
>
> Casting an evil spell is not an alignment infraction in and of itself, though it may violate a character's code or tenets of faith. Commiting an evil act outside of casting a spell, such as using an evil spell to torment an innocent NPC, is an alignment infraction.

So casting *Create Undead* is not automatically an alignment infraction that will earn you Infamy in Pathfinder Society. However, the usage of those undead for evil things will. Additionally, you may have to navigate the tenets of faith of other restrictions from the PCs in your party.

Ultimately, the decision about when a Infamy is deserved is the GM's discretion, but casting [evil] spells themselves is okay.